# Finding coprime solutions to Diophantine equations

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I'm hoping to use Mathematica to find solutions to Diophantine equations. Below is a toy example of something I would like to try.

Consider the case of $$x^2+y^2 = 17$$

which has the solution $x=1,y=4$. Note that $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

Suppose I didn't know this, and I wanted to use Mathematica to find a solution to $x^2+y^2 = 17$ where $x$ and $y$ were coprime.

As a piece of example code, I would try something like

```
FindInstance[
 x^2 + y^2 == 17 && x > 0 && y > 0 && CoprimeQ[x, y], {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

However, this returns no solution. I'm not entirely sure what the trouble is; I suspect the trouble is that though `CoprimeQ[1,4]` returns True, `CoprimeQ[x,y]` returns False, even when I've cleared $x$ and $y$.

Is there a way to pair CoprimeQ and FindInstance to find a coprime solution to a Diophantine equation? Or is there a better method for proceeding?

Comment: You have a superfluous "z". However, I think this is a bug of "FindInstance."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 17 && x > 0 && y > 0 && GCD[x, y]==1, {x, y}, Integers]
```

returns

```
(x==1&&y==4)||(x==4&&y==1)
```

and

```
FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == 17 && x > 0 && y > 0 && GCD[x, y]==1, {x, y}, Integers]
```

returns

```
{{x->4,y->1}}
```

But why does `FindInstance` with `CoprimeQ` fail? `Trace` might give a clue.

```
Trace[FindInstance[x^2+y^2==17&&x>0&&y>0&&CoprimeQ[x,y],{x,y,z},Integers]]
```

returns

```
{{x^2+y^2==17&&x>0&&y>0&&CoprimeQ[x,y], 
 {CoprimeQ[x,y],False},False}, 
 FindInstance[False,{x,y,z},Integers]],{}}
```

so it appears it is the `CoprimeQ` which is making this fail

Comment: Since `CoprimeQ` ends in `Q` it always evaluates to `True` or `False`, even with symbolic arguments.